# Create a relational GWAS/Genomics database

Tags: database, bioinformatics, genetics

I thought I'd ask before I try to build something from scratch.

Here is the type of problem I need to answer.  One of our researchers comes to me and says "How many people in our data have such-and-such SNP genotyped?"

Our genetics data consists of several dozen GWAS files, typically flat delimited.  Each GWAS file has between 100,000-1,000,000 SNPs.  There is some overlap in the SNPs, but less than I'd originally thought.

Anyway, what I want to do is have some sort of structured database that links our participant IDs to a particular GWAS study, and then link that GWAS study to a list of SNPs, and I can write some kind of query that will pull all IDs that have the data.  At no point do I need individual level genotype data, it is way easier to pull the SNP/Samples that I need once I know where they are.

So that is my problem and what I'm looking for.  For anyone who works with a lot of GWAS data, I'm sure you're familiar with the problem.  Is there anything (free or paid) that is built for this type of problem?  Or do you have thoughts on what direction I might want to go if I need to build this myself?

Thanks.